# How can I solve a series of differential equations in Matlab only until the solution reaches a certain value, then stop?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I'm solving a series of ODEs in Matlab using ode23 that all 'blow up' for different values. Instead of stating a range to solve over, I want to tell Matlab to solve the equation until the solution becomes greater than a certain amount (1000, say) and then stop, so that I don't have to manually find the solvable range for each equation. Is there a way to do this? I want to do this so I can state a range of values that is the same for each ODE, but each equation is only solved on a subset of that range.

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html

Comment: This is essentially a question about software features.  If the actual ODE were stated, one might ask if it were necessarily true that the function value would eventually reach a specified limit (e.g. $1000$), and that would be on-topic.

Comment: Looks on-topic to me. The Matlab tag states: *"For mathematical questions about MATLAB"*. Finding an event with an ODE solver looks quite mathematical to me.